# Enabling C++ exceptions on ARM bare-metal bootloader

Tags: c++, exception, arm, bootloader

For learning purpose, I am trying to get full C++ support on an ARM MCU (STM32F407ZE). I am struggling at getting exceptions working, consequently carrying this question:

**How to get C++ exceptions on a bare-metal ARM bootloader?**

To extend a bit the question:
I understand that an exception, like exiting a function require unwinding the stack. The fact that exiting a function works out of the box, but the exception handling does not, make me to think that the compiler is adding the unwinding of functions-exit but can not do it for exceptions.

So the sub-question 1 is: Is this premise correct? Do I really need to implement/integrate an unwinding library for exception handling?

In my superficial understanding of unwinding, there is a frame in the stack and the unwinding "just" need to call the destructor on each object of it, and finally jump to the given `catch`.

Sub-question 2 is: How does the unwinding library perform this task? What is the strategy used? (to the extends appropriate for a SO answer)

In my searches, I found many explanations of WHAT is the unwinding, but very few of how to get it working. The closest is:

[GCC arm-none-eabi (Codesourcery) and C++ Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151397/gcc-arm-none-eabi-codesourcery-and-c-exceptions)

---

### The project

1) The first step and yet with some difficulties, was to get the MCU powered and communicating through JTAG.

> This is just contextual information, please do not tag the question off-topic just because of this picture. Jump to step 2 instead.

I know there are testing boards available, but this is a learning project to get a better understanding on all the "magic" behind the scene. So I got a chip socket, a bread-board and setup the minimal power-up circuitry:

[image]

Note: JTAG is performed through the GPIO of a raspberry-pi.
Note2: I am using OpenOCD to communicate with the chip.

2) Second step, was to make a minimal software to blink the yellow led.
Using arm-none-eabi-g++ as a compiler and linker, the c++ code was straightforward, but my understanding of the linker script is still somewhat blurry.

3) Enable exceptions handling (not yet working).

For this goal, following informations where useful:

- https://wiki.osdev.org/C++_Exception_Support
- https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/exceptions.pdf
- https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html

However, it seems quite too much complexity for a simple exception handling, and before to start implementing/integrating an unwinding library, I would like to be sure I am going in the correct direction.
I would like to avoid earing in 2 weeks: "Ohh, by the way, you just need to add this "-xx" option to the compiler and it works"

main.cpp

```
auto reset_handler() noexcept ->void;
auto main() -> int;

int global_variable_test=50;

extern "C"
{

        #include "stm32f4xx.h"
        #include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
        #include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"



        void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line){}
        void hardFaultHandler( unsigned int * hardFaultArgs);

        // vector table
        #define SRAM_SIZE 128*1024
        #define SRAM_END        (SRAM_BASE + SRAM_SIZE)
        unsigned long *vector_table[] __attribute__((section(".vector_table"))) =
        {
                (unsigned long *)SRAM_END,   // initial stack pointer 
                (unsigned long *)reset_handler,        // main as Reset_Handler
        };
}


auto reset_handler() noexcept -> void
{
        // Setup execution

        // Call the main function
        int ret = main();

        // never finish
        while(true);
}


class A
{
public:
        int b;

        auto cppFunc()-> void
        {
                throw (int)4;
        }
};

auto main() -> int
{
        // Initializing led GPIO
        RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOG, ENABLE);
        GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitDef;

        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14;
        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
        GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitDef);

        // Testing normal blinking
        int loopNum = 500000;
        for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        {
                loopNum = 100000;
                GPIO_SetBits(GPIOG, GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14);
                for (int i = 0; i < loopNum; i++) continue; //active waiting!

                loopNum = 800000;
                GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOG, GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14);
                for (int i=0; i<loopNum; i++) continue; //active waiting!
        }

        // Try exceptions handling
        try
        {
                A a;
                a.cppFunc();
        }
        catch(...){}


        return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
CPP_C = arm-none-eabi-g++
C_C = arm-none-eabi-g++
LD = arm-none-eabi-g++
COPY = arm-none-eabi-objcopy

LKR_SCRIPT = -Tstm32_minimal.ld

INCLUDE = -I. -I./stm32f4xx/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I./stm32f4xx/CMSIS/Include -I./stm32f4xx/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc -I./stm32f4xx/Utilities/STM32_EVAL/STM3240_41_G_EVAL -I./stm32f4xx/Utilities/STM32_EVAL/Common
C_FLAGS  = -c -fexceptions -fno-common -O0 -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -DSTM32F40XX -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER $(INCLUDE)
CPP_FLAGS  = -std=c++11 -c $(C_FLAGS)
LFLAGS  = -specs=nosys.specs -nostartfiles -nostdlib $(LKR_SCRIPT)
CPFLAGS = -Obinary

all: main.bin

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CPP_C) $(CPP_FLAGS) -o main.o main.cpp

stm32f4xx_gpio.o: stm32f4xx_gpio.c
        $(C_C) $(C_FLAGS) -o stm32f4xx_gpio.o stm32f4xx_gpio.c

stm32f4xx_rcc.o: stm32f4xx_rcc.c
        $(C_C) $(C_FLAGS) -o stm32f4xx_rcc.o stm32f4xx_rcc.c

main.elf: main.o stm32f4xx_gpio.o stm32f4xx_rcc.o
        $(LD) $(LFLAGS) -o main.elf main.o stm32f4xx_gpio.o stm32f4xx_rcc.o

main.bin: main.elf
        $(COPY) $(CPFLAGS) main.elf main.bin

clean:
        rm -rf *.o *.elf *.bin

write:
        ./write_bin.sh main.elf
```

Linker script: stm32_minimal.ld

```
/* memory layout for an STM32F407 */
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
    SRAM (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
}

/* output sections */
SECTIONS
{
    /* program code into FLASH */
    .text :
    {
        *(.vector_table)    /* Vector table */
        *(.text)            /* Program code */
        *(.data)
        /**(.eh_frame)*/
    } >FLASH

    .ARM.exidx :            /* Required for unwinding the stack? */
    {
        __exidx_start = .;
        * (.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
        __exidx_end   = .;
    } > FLASH

    PROVIDE ( end = . );

}
```

Comment: `there is a frame in the stack and the unwinding "just" need to call the destructor on each object of it, and finally jump to the given catch.` - no, there's (potentially) a hierarchy of active exception frames (try blocks) on stack, arranged as a linked list. The actual exception may well occur further down the hierarchy, outside an explicit frame. The unwinder must inspect each active frame, which may contain a finally block, a catch block, or both. Finally block must be executed, catch blocks must too, if they match the exception. This is just scratching the surface. Use a library.

Comment: Most high-quality exception-handling implementations rely on tables that indicate which destructors and `catch` blocks apply to any given program counter value, so as to avoid burdening the non-exceptional path with recording them on every execution.

Comment: Thank you for you comments. Is there any further explanation on this? (Before to jump to those 100+ pages spec.).