# C++ Exceptions and Static Linking

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, raspberry-pi, g++

I'm trying to use exceptions in a C++ code that runs on raspberry-pi zero.
When I link the code dynamically it works fine.
However, when I link it **statically**, I get:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::exception'
terminate called recursively
Aborted

An example code to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)  
{  
    throw std::exception();  
}  

int main (void)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        foo();  
    }  
    catch(...)  
    {  
        printf("caught an exception\n");  
    }  

    return (0);  
}
```

My "problematic" link command is:
g++ exceptionTest.cpp -o exceptionTest.out --static

**Why does the static linking disrupts the exceptions mechanism?**
**Is there something I could do in my link command (e.g. add flags) to fix this?**

*Note: my problem appears very similar to 
[GCC arm-none-eabi (Codesourcery) and C++ Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151397/gcc-arm-none-eabi-codesourcery-and-c-exceptions)
but the OP there worked on a different system and the suggested solution was related to a link script (which I don't use).*

Comment: The exact same problem occurs in the raspberry-pi-2 and raspberry-pi-3 as well.

Comment: Can you try adding `-fexceptions` ?

Comment: I tried adding "-fexceptions" and the problem remained.

Comment: Try passing `-static` instead of `--static`. The latter seems like a direct linker option, so the driver might not handle it completely correctly. (just an idea though, not sure if this makes any sense)

Comment: "-static" doesn't help either.